# Glue vector to string

Tags: r, r-glue

I want to produce this string: 
`All my variables: a, b, c` from this variable `vars <- c("a", "b", "c")` using `glue()`.

My best attempt so far is:

```
library(glue)
glue('All my variables: {paste(vars, collapse = ", ")}')
```

**Question:**

Is there any easier / cleaner way of to implement it that i oversee?

**Other attempts:**

The following obviously fail, i just want to show that i looked into the docu and made some effort :).

```
glue('All my variables: {vars}')
glue_data('All my variables: {vars}', .sep = ", ")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do,

```
paste('All my variables:', toString(vars))
#[1] "All my variables: a, b, c"
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. As specified i would like to stay with glue (for consistency). But `toString()` is great and can be combined with glue as i saw. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

you can also use `glue::glue_collapse()` :

```
vars <- c("a", "b", "c")
glue("All my variables : {glue_collapse(vars,  sep = ', ')}")
#> All my variables : a, b, c
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily without any packages at all.  Here are some possibilities:

```
# 1
paste("All my variables:", toString(vars))
## [1] "All my variables: a, b, c"

# 2
sprintf("All my variables: %s", toString(vars))
## [1] "All my variables: a, b, c"

# 3
sub("@", toString(vars), "All my variables: @")
## [1] "All my variables: a, b, c"
```

If you are looking to do this to output a warning or error message:

```
# 4a
warning("All my variables: ", toString(vars))
## Warning message:
## All my variables: a, b, c 

# 4b
stop("All my variables: ", toString(vars))
## Error: All my variables: a, b, c
```

With `fn$` from the gsubfn package.  Preface any function call with `fn$` (such as `c` here) and then the arguments will be processed using quasi-perl string interpolation.

```
# 5
library(gsubfn)
fn$c("All my variables: `toString(vars)`")
## [1] "All my variables: a, b, c"
```

or

```
# 6
library(gsubfn)
string <- toString(vars)
fn$c("All my variables: $string")
## [1] "All my variables: a, b, c"
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. As specified i would like to stay with glue (for consistency). But `toString()` is great and can be combined with glue as i saw. Thanks a lot! I accepted Sotos answer as he was a bit faster, i hope thats fine for you.

Comment: Actually the question asked was "Is there any easier / cleaner way of to implement it that i oversee?" and eliminating dependencies with no additional complication seems cleaner.

Comment: fair Point. I wasnt specific enough there, sry.